# Android : Gradle build while running the app taking too long on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: android, ubuntu, gradle

I have recently updated ubuntu from 14.04 to 16.04.

I have installed the latest version of `android studio`, 2.1.3. When I build the first app that is "Hello world" app, it is taking around 4 minutes to build.

I have enabled the offline work option in `gradle` settings and also the parallel execution in compiler settings.

**studio64.vmoptions**

```
-Xms256m
-Xmx1280m
-XX:MaxPermSize=350m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-da
-Djna.nosys=true
-Djna.boot.library.path=

-Djna.debug_load=true
-Djna.debug_load.jna=true
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=lcd
```

I am on a 64-bit machine with 4GB RAM and 250GB HDD.

Comment: did you try increasing the heap for gradle? `android {
 dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "3g"
}`. 4GB of RAM for development is not enough. Please consider doubling your RAM.

Comment: added gradle tag and some code formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gradle have recently published a great guide called [Improving the performance of Gradle builds](https://gradle.github.io/performance-guide/). The chapter that you'll find useful is about [profiling](https://gradle.github.io/performance-guide/#_profile_profile_profile). Run the build, notice any performance bottlenecks and act accordingly. It's hard to tell what exactly is slowing down your build.